# Overlap of Group Barcharts in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Dataset:

[image]

Code to plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
n_groups = 6
GreenTaxi = pivot_df['GreenTaxi'].tolist()
YellowTaxi = pivot_df['YellowTaxi'].tolist()
Uber = pivot_df['Uber'].tolist()

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, GreenTaxi, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 label='GreenTaxi')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, YellowTaxi, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',
                 label='YellowTaxi')

rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, Uber, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='r',
                 label='Uber')

plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Ride Counts')
plt.title('Rides By Month')
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.xticks(index + bar_width,pivot_df['MonthName'].tolist() )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The green and red bar charts are overlapping and more over MonthName does not come in the x label ,only  numerics are coming . Could you please advise on th eissue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), also first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with column `Names` and then change order of columns by subset `[]`:

```
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8
colors = ['b','g','r']
cols = ['GreenTaxi','YellowTaxi','Uber']
title = 'Rides By Month'
ylabel = "Ride Counts"

ax = pivot_df.set_index('MonthName')[cols].plot.bar(width=bar_width,
                                                    alpha=opacity, 
                                                    figsize=(5,5), 
                                                    color=colors, 
                                                    title=title)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
ax.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':10})
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=["Jan","Feb","March","April"],columns=["Uber","T1", "T2"])

df.plot(kind='bar',rot=0)
```

[image]